# wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Could not download wasm module

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

i was working on a flutter Project where i have a form with a textfield and image picker and while runing my project i get this sentence on debug console .

Comment: the sentence is this :wasm streaming compile failed: TypeError: Could not download wasm module

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.